# How to calculate with rows in a column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, calculation

I am trying to do calculations with rows in a column:
I have the following data for one product:

```
Day    Price
1      3$
2      12$
3      4$
4      2$
5      4$
```

I want to divide the price change of a day by the day before so, for example for Day 2:

```
12$/3$ = 4
```

Results should be:

```
Day    Price    Calculation
1      3$       NA
2      12$      4
3      4$       0,33
4      2$       0,5
5      4$       2
```

I have a list of 5000 prices. I am also concerned how to get the NA in Day 1 were no calculation is possible.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may divide the current value by the previous value (`lag`).  The `$` is not considered in the `numeric` class.  We may need to extract the `numeric` value (`parse_number`) does that and do the calculation

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df1 %>%
    mutate(Calculation = readr::parse_number(as.character(Price)),
        Calculation = round(Calculation/lag(Calculation), 2))
```

-output

```
df1
 Day Price Calculation
1   1    3$          NA
2   2   12$        4.00
3   3    4$        0.33
4   4    2$        0.50
5   5    4$        2.00
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Day = 1:5, Price = c("3$", "12$", "4$", "2$", 
"4$")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: Thank for the quick response, trying your code I receive a error: `Error: Problem with mutate() column Calculation`.
`i Calculation = readr::parse_number(Price)`.
`x is.character(x) is not TRUE`

Comment: @upflow maybe you have`factor` class. Try with `as.character` as in my updated code

Comment: Thank you, A calculation is done now. But the new column "Calculation" is still missing somehow.

Comment: @upflow just do the assignment `<-` back to original data i.e. `df1 <- df1 %>%
    mutate(Calculation = readr::parse_number(as.character(Price)),
        Calculation = round(Calculation/lag(Calculation), 2))`

Comment: Thanks, now I have the needed results! A short question: Is there a possibility to duplicate the column `Price`, but to put the price data one row down? So for `Day 2`: the original `Price` will be 12 and for `Price_duplicate` it will be 3?

Comment: @upflow You can add `df1 <- df1 %>%
    mutate(Price_duplicate= lag(Price), Calculation = readr::parse_number(as.character(Price)),
        Calculation = round(Calculation/lag(Calculation), 2))`

Answer (score 2):

Here is `dplyr` only solution using `gsub` instead of `parse_number`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(Calculation=as.numeric(gsub("\\$", "", Price)),
         Calculation=round(Calculation/lag(Calculation), 2))
```

```
Day Price Calculation
1   1    3$          NA
2   2   12$        4.00
3   3    4$        0.33
4   4    2$        0.50
5   5    4$        2.00
```

Answer (score 1):

Base R option -

Change `Price` column to numeric and subtract the current `Price` value with the previous one.

```
df$Price <- as.numeric(sub('$', '', df$Price, fixed = TRUE))
df$Calculation <-  c(NA, df$Price[-1]/df$Price[-nrow(df)])
df
#  Day Price Calculation
#1   1     3          NA
#2   2    12       4.000
#3   3     4       0.333
#4   4     2       0.500
#5   5     4       2.000
```